# Getting information of clicked button (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making the board game Puerto Rico in C++ and Qt. One of the features will be that after they've chosen the Major Role (button 1) each player (3 players in total) kan build a building. So i have a button for each building, is there a way that i get the information (like the name of the button) when the player clicked on it?

Kind regards

Comment: Probably Qt provides some means of reflecting a button click back to a method on a button object. If not, then inspect the event object in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect a signal of `QPushButton` to a slot, you can call `sender()` inside the slot to get the object which sent the signal.

Example slot code:

```
void MainWindow::onButtonPress()
{
    QObject* senderObj = sender();
    if (senderObj->isWidgetType())
    {
        QPushButton* button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(senderObj);
        if (button)
        {
           // button is the QPushButton who emmited this signal
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created `building1Button`, `building2Button`, `building3Button` buttons in the designer, you can try the followings.

In your class constructor you need to connect the `clicked()` SIGNAL from all building buttons to the same SLOT.

```
Game::Game()
{
    // ...

    connect( ui->building1Button, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( onBuildingClicked() ) );
    connect( ui->building2Button, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( onBuildingClicked() ) );
    connect( ui->building3Button, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( onBuildingClicked() ) );

    // ...
}
```

And in that SLOT you can use `sender()` function to check which button was clicked.

```
void Game::onBuildingClicked()
{
    QPushButton* clickedButton = qobject_cast< QPushButton* >( sender() );
    if ( clickedButton )
    {
        const QString clickedBuilding   = clickedButton->text();
        const QString clickedButtonName = clickedButton->objectName();
    }
}
```